# How do you change values in a column of a dataframe to a part of the current value?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working on cleaning a dataframe.  One of the columns is "Year" and contains values in the following format:

"2012-2013"

I would like to change the values in the column to just show the latter year:

"2013"

Comment: Use `trimws("2012-2013", whitespace = ".*-")` or for the dataset `df1$Year <- trimws(df1$year, whitespace = ".*-")`

Comment: `unlist(strsplit("2012-2013", "-"))[-2]`

Answer (score 0):

Try substring value from left to right in data frame column - like 6 to 9 digit value

```
v$new<-substr(v[,1] , 6,9)

2013
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using tidyverse functions. `str_sub` takes a string and extracts the values between the starting and ending positions provided.

```
dat <- data.frame(year = c('2012-2013', '2013-2014'))
dat %>% mutate(new_year = str_sub(year, start = 6, end = 9))
```